# jquery to update element with new value

Tags: jquery

how can i use jquery to update the value inside these tags `<center></center>`

**HERE IS THE HTML**

```
<h1 id="total_contacts"><center>0</center></h1>
```

**HERE IS MY JQUERY**

I don't think my jquery is targeting the center tags.

```
$("#total_contacts").text(total_contacts);
```

Comment: Probably just a typo, but if it isn't, you'll want to correct that too.  `$("#total_contacts")`

Comment: $("#total_contacts center").text('total_contacts');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

►The id you are using is wrong.

```
 $("#total_contacts center").text(total_contacts);//not $("#total_contatcs")
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$("#total_contacts center").text('Hi user3436467');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="total_contacts"><center>0</center></h1>
```

Comment: Please correct the typo that the OP made (contatcs).

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id="total_contacts"><center>0</center></h1>
<script>
$("#total_contacts center").html("5");
</script>
```

write your variable instead of 5 in your js and be sure that add jquery to your html